# How to use outputs of php that is called by ajax in our file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an app that sends latitude, longitude values to my postgresql database. And i want to plot the updated points accordingly on my OpenLayers map using jquery,ajax. But here is where i am stuck at: When I click the button, the php file with database connection and saving the last entry of the table in an array is happening.

But when i try using the outputs in markers, nothing is happening.

How to use the output values of the php in my function?

Here is the code that i am trying to use.

php file:

```
<?php
$conn = pg_connect("host=xxx port=xxx dbname=xx user=postgres password=xxx");
$result = pg_exec($conn,"Query goes here");
$numrows = pg_numrows($result);
for($ri = 0; $ri < $numrows; $ri++)
{
$row = pg_fetch_array($result, $ri);
$data = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
  $lat_latest[] = $row["latitude"];
$long_latest[] = $row["longitude"];  // add the row in to the results (data) array
}
pg_close($conn);
$js_lat = json_encode($lat_latest);
echo "var javascript_lat1 = ". $js_lat . ";\n";
$js_long = json_encode($long_latest);
echo "var javascript_long1 = ". $js_long . ";\n";
?>
```

My page code is :

```
function init(){
//openlayers map code is here.
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("dataconn.php",function(data,status){

    alert("Data:"+data+"Status:" +status);
    var extra_point = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
     new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(parseFloat(javascript_long1[0]),parseFloat(javascript_lat1[0])),
     {some:'data'},
     {externalGraphic: 'images1/marker-gold.png', graphicHeight: 16, graphicWidth: 16});
     vectorLayer1.addFeatures([extra_point]);
    });
    });
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='init();'>
    <div id="map" style = 'width: 1075px; height: 485px'>
    <button> Update </button>
    </div>
```

and the alert i am getting when clicking update button is

```
Data: 
var javascript_lat1 = ["output of the query"];
var javascript_long1 = ["output of the query"];
Status : success
```

Is the way i am trying to access the values of query output correct? Please help.
Sorry if this is a dumb question. I am new to jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your php script sends a string like:

```
'var javascript_lat1 = ["output of the query"];'
```

back to your code, that does not mean that your code has a variable called javascript_lat1 in it.

Your php script is sending *strings* back to your javascript code from which you must extract the information that you want to use in your code.  It is up to your javascript code to know what format the strings are in.  But since you wrote the php script you can send the strings back in any format you want.  Then your javascript code can dissect the strings with regexes, split(), etc. to extract the parts of the strings that you want to use in your code.  A very simple format that your php code could use is:

```
"output of query 1, output of query 2"
```

Then you can split() on the comma to separate the two pieces of data e.g.:

```
var pieces = data.split(', ');
```

Then you can use pieces[0] and pieces[1] in your javascript code.

Another option is to send a request to your php script using the $.getJSON() function.  If you do that, your php script should send back a json formatted string, e.g.:

```
"{lat1: 'blah blah blah', long1: 'foo bar foo bar'}"
```

Then the $.getJSON() function will automatically convert the string into a javascript object  and pass the js object to your callback function.  Inside the callback function you can access the data using:

```
some_func(data.lat1, data.long1);
```

Comment: @luffymonkey, Not at all.  You'll be running FB in no time.